# onchange event on calender is not working in calender.js

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I have an html element with default value as shown

```
<input type="text" id="start_date" name="start_date" value="2014-12-17"  onClick="scwShow(this,this);" onFocus="scwShow(this,this);" class="textboxstyle">
```

On click of this input field, calender is getting opened from calender.js, after selecting/changing date, I want to do an ajax call, so I want to have onchange click event in my javascript. My javascript code is

```
$("#start_date").on("change", function(e){
     console.log("changed date is:"+ $("#start_date").val());
});
```

But here on changing date from date picker in input field, onchange event is not triggering. Is that external library(calender.js) not allowing me to trigger onchange event after changing date? Any solution??

Answer (score 1):

There is just the "Data" input type with HTML5, use it instead of javascript/JQuery plugins!

```
<input type="date" onchange="yourfunction(e)">
```

Comment: we need to support legacy when it to use. In addition I can not change the existing code which is using this JQuery plugin. So please how can I get this triggered event .

Comment: you might read the code of this plugin, and see how it changes the value of the input field, so to understand why the change event isn't triggered!
You can also post a snippet of this funcionality in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and next link me to help you.